# robotframework selenium2library how to catch both javascript exception and !=200 http status response

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework

i want to improve my selenium2library robotframework testsuite catching javascript error and calls that returns http status different from 200.

Even i think this is a common problem, google cannot help me.

Some advices?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test http responses, you need another library such as [RequestsLibrary](https://github.com/bulkan/robotframework-requests/#readme)  or [HTTPLibrary](https://github.com/peritus/robotframework-httplibrary/#readme). You can also write your own keywords in python using `urllib2` or `urllib3`.

You can use Selenium2Library's [ExecuteJavascript](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Execute%20Javascript) keyword to test javascript functions.

Comment: i already use RequestsLibrary to make requests but i need something to catch every calls made opening web page in order to understand if something fails. I can obtain this result by javascript probes (es, for example, trackjs) but if possibile i prefer to listen every calls without inject trackjs.

Comment: thanks, but i need something passive. i want to navigate normally in website that i'm testing and simultaneously and passively catch error http status (for example 404)